# How can I generate reports containing charts with Pentaho and Java?

Tags: java, reporting, business-intelligence, pentaho

We have a Java EE based web application and we want to integrate Pentaho reporting API into this application.

So, I'm trying to learn how Pentaho can automatically generate reports containing charts. I have downloaded Pentaho BI server and played with it for a few days. But I'm still clueless about the following issues:

1. How to generate reports dynamically at runtime without loading those *.prpt files.
2. Where I can get a simple tutorial about dynamic report generation
3. What the difference is between Community Dashboard Framework, charting tools and reporting tools.

The documentation on the Community Dashboard Framework site is not properly organized, and there is not a single tutorial about getting started.

If anyone can help me find the answers to some of my questions, it will be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define reports purely via the API of the reporting engine. Samrat is right on that the preferred way of defining reports is the report designer - as code changes are harder to maintain than changes of a GUI-editable external report definition.

I think the best way to go forward is to grab Will Gorman's book about "Pentaho Reporting 3.5 for Java Developers" which gives you a deep insight into the inner workings of the reporting engine and also how to define reports dynamically.

CDF vs Reporting: CDF is a javascript toolkit for creating interactive dashboards. Dashboards are aimed to provide a high-level overview over the state of your company with the ability to drill down or even customize them. Reports produced by the reporting engine are predefined/"canned" reports that we expect to be run frequently to answer specific business questions. Charts components are just components that produce a given chart for dashboards based on a set of input parameters.

CDF uses reports and charts as content in dashboards.

Answer (score 1):

Without prpt files there is no pentaho reporting. To achieve dynamically, run the pentaho BI server and pass the parameters to the report. Load the report in iframe.

Comment: Thanks Samrat.. Where can I get information about how to generate those prpt files?

Comment: The design of your pentaho Report is a PRPT file. You can do this using Report-Designer. http://reporting.pentaho.com/report_designer.php