# Does it make sense to build a django webapp integrating the Pentaho CDF

Tags: django, business-intelligence, pentaho

Can Pentaho CDF be integrated in a django webapp for the reporting module of this webapp?

We need to present our data in a "BI user" way, allowing users to explore our data, such as drill-down, click the details... What this the approach we should leverage Pentaho in this scenario?

1) leveraging its CDF to produce charting?

2) leveraging its report designer to design the individual chart?

3) leveraging its report designer to design the dashboard layout? -- it seems that we should have my django app control the layout.

I think my question is related to the following question (just I am thinking of Django instead of Java EE)
[How can I generate reports containing charts with Pentaho and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723790/how-to-generate-report-containing-chart-using-pentaho-and-java)

Also, these two posts seem to be related to my thinking as well [How to build Charts in Pentaho? using xAction or using CDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258278/how-to-build-charts-in-pentaho-using-xaction-or-using-cdf)

[Integrating Pentaho Reporting web frontend with custom Java/JSF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443572/integrating-pentaho-reporting-web-frontend-with-custom-java-jsf-application)

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering leveraging the reporting module and analytic tool of Pentaho along with CDF, I would suggest integrating [Saiku](http://analytical-labs.com/) as there is no more support for JPivot in Pentaho.

Comment: I think my question is more about whether I should use Pentaho BI server as my webapp server. (I am new to webapp dev)

Comment: Hmm, that would be more appropriate, as the Pentaho BI server contains most of what you would need.